# Writing an iterative algorithm recursive, but I don´t see what Im doing wrong

Tags: java

I´m trying to write an iterative algorithm recursive, but my code isn´t working. This is my iterative algorithm:

```
public long calculate(long n) {

 int var = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var += ((var - 1) + (var - 3));
}

return var;
```

And this is what I have tried for the recursive one:

```
public long calculate(long n) {


if (n <= 2) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return n + calculate((n - 1) + (n - 3));
}
```

I just started learning recursive algorithms and I can´t see why this doesn´t work. Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Iterative: `n` and `var` are to different values

Recursive: there is only `n`, so not the same *formula* as before - simplest solution, use two parameters instead of just one

---

<sup>Note: not a good example of a problem to solve by recursion, neither the best way to develop (transform an iterative algorithm to recursive). Recursive solutions are best suited for recursive problems... INHO</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The calculation in the iterative method may be rewritten as:

```java
public static long calculateIterative(long n) {
    int var = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        var += 2 * (var - 2); //((var - 1) + (var - 3));
    }
    
    return var;
}
```

Here we can see that for n = 0 it returns 0, for n = 1, var = -4, for n = 2: -4 + 2 * (-4 - 2) = -16, etc.

Thus, the recursive function has to "imitate" compound assignment and can be transformed:

`var += 2 * (var - 2);` -> `var = var + 2 * (var - 2);` -> `var = 3 * var - 4;`

so finally it may look like this:

```java
public static long calculate(long n) {

    if (n <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    return 3 * calculate(n - 1) - 4;
}
```

tests:

```java
for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
    System.out.printf("iterative(%d)=%-6d  recursive(%d)=%-6d%n", 
        n, calculateIterative(n), n, calculate(n)
    );
}
```

Output:

```
iterative(0)=0       recursive(0)=0     
iterative(1)=-4      recursive(1)=-4    
iterative(2)=-16     recursive(2)=-16   
iterative(3)=-52     recursive(3)=-52   
iterative(4)=-160    recursive(4)=-160  
iterative(5)=-484    recursive(5)=-484  
iterative(6)=-1456   recursive(6)=-1456 
iterative(7)=-4372   recursive(7)=-4372 
iterative(8)=-13120  recursive(8)=-13120
iterative(9)=-39364  recursive(9)=-39364
```